Share values from child to parent
I would like to achieve common tags to be included with a set of other tags. Let's assume this is my working directory tree:
├── README.md
├── _envcommon
│   └── eks-vpc.hcl
├── non-production
│   ├── account.hcl
│   └── eu-west-3
│       ├── dev
│       │   ├── eks-vpc
│       │   │   └── terragrunt.hcl
│       │   └── env.hcl
│       ├── region.hcl
└── terragrunt.hcl

What I'm trying to achieve is that fron ./non-production/eu-west-1/dev/eks-vpc/terragrunt.hcl to fetch additional_tags from _envcommon/eks_vpc.hcl and then pass them to the  generate "provider"block in theroot` config.
./non-production/eu-west-1/dev/eks-vpc/terragrunt.hcl:
# config common to all terragrunt repository
include "root" {
  path   = find_in_parent_folders()
  expose = true
}

# Module common values
include "envcommon"{
    path = "${dirname(find_in_parent_folders())}/_envcommon/vpc.hcl"
    # Should contain values that are common to all environments in which this module will be used in.
    expose = true
}

terraform {
  source = "${include.envcommon.locals.base_url}?ref=v1.0.0"
}

inputs = {
    ... other input values
}

./_envcommon/vpc.hcl:
locals {
  additional_tags={
    "Criticality"       = "critical"
    "Supporting:Tools"  = true
  }
}

./terragrunt.hcl:
locals {
  account_vs     = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("account.hcl"))

  environment_vs = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("env.hcl"))

  account_id         = local.account_vs.locals.aws_account_id
  profile            = "<aws_profile_name>"
  region             = "eu-west-1"

  common_tags = {
      env            = "${local.environment_vs.locals.environment}"
      controlledBy   = "terraform"
  }

  tags = merge(local.common_tags, additional_tags_fetched_from_envcommon)
}


generate "provider" {
  path      = "provider.tf"
  if_exists = "skip"
  contents  = <<EOF
provider "aws" {
  region = "${local.region}"
  profile = "${local.profile}"
  # Only these AWS Account IDs may be operated on by this template
  allowed_account_ids = ["${local.account_id}"]
  default_tags {
    tags = ${jsonencode(local.tags)}
  }
}
EOF
}

remote_state {
  ... remote_state_config
}

vpc configuration is an example and I actually have other modules I'm using and this approach would make life easier to inject different default_tags per module

can you explain the error you are receiving? I didn't look in depth in the vars, but theoretically it should work.

I don't have an error, im after ideas on how to achieve this

It looks like your configuration doesn't work because variable resolution in the include path isn't functioning properly, as mentioned in these this and this github issues.
However, I found a workaround that might be suitable for you.
In the ./non-production/eu-west-1/dev/eks-vpc/terragrunt.hcl, you can add the following include block:
include "test" {
  path = "${get_terragrunt_dir()}/../../../../_envcommon/eks_vpc.hcl"
  expose = true
}

Then, you can reference to this variables like:
additional_tags = "${include.test.locals.additional_tags}"
You can check this link for more info end examples.
